# exact string matching in two lists in python

Tags: python, dynamic-programming

I need to match two lists one with characters and other with words
My current code is:

```
char_list=['G','UH','D','S', 'ER', 'M', 'AY', 'S', 'EH', 'L', 'F', 'B', 'AE', 'NG', 'K']
word_list=['GUHD','MAORNIHNG','SER','MAY','SEHLF','BAENGK']


for word_p in word_list:
    scores = {}
    p_s=""
    if str(word_p) != "NULL":
        print(word_p)
        for j in char_list:
            if len(word_p) == len(p_s):
                print("word end")
                for i in scores.keys():
                    char_list.remove(i)
                break
            else:
                if j in word_p:
                    p_s=p_s+j
                    scores[j] = gop_scores.get(str(j))#this returns an integer value corresponding to char 

        sep_scores[str(word_p)] = scores 
print(sep_scores)
```

The current output is:-

```
*{'GUHD': {'G': 100.0, 'UH': 18.142809657631524, 'D': 61.62375099467158}, 'MAORNIHNG': {'M': 100.0, 'NG': 43.40719714138942}, 'SER': {'S': 100.0, 'ER': 100.0}, 'MAY': {'M': 100.0, 'AY': 100.0}, 'SEHLF': {'S': 100.0, 'EH': 89.72295878282416, 'L': 100.0, 'F': 0.0}, 'BAENGK': {'B': 7.166608749080874, 'AE': 68.10287800038276, 'NG': 43.40719714138942, 'K': 100.0}}}*
```

**Note**

Everything seems fine but there is no exact matching char for MAORNIHNG and still i am getting{'M','NG'}, I want the MAORNIHNG value to be empty

**expected output**

```
*{'GUHD': {'G': 100.0, 'UH': 18.142809657631524, 'D': 61.62375099467158}, 'MAORNIHNG': {}, 'SER': {'S': 100.0, 'ER': 100.0}, 'MAY': {'M': 100.0, 'AY': 100.0}, 'SEHLF': {'S': 100.0, 'EH': 89.72295878282416, 'L': 100.0, 'F': 0.0}, 'BAENGK': {'B': 7.166608749080874, 'AE': 68.10287800038276, 'NG': 43.40719714138942, 'K': 100.0}}}*
```

The 'MAORNIHNG' value should be empty dict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to make sure that the dictionary keys form the entire word, and if not return an empty dict, you can do this by joining them and comparing:

```py
char_list=['G','UH','D','S', 'ER', 'M', 'AY', 'S', 'EH', 'L', 'F', 'B', 'AE', 'NG', 'K']
word_list=['GUHD','MAORNIHNG','SER','MAY','SEHLF','BAENGK']

sep_scores={}
for word_p in word_list:
    scores = {}
    p_s=""
    if str(word_p) != "NULL":
        print(word_p)
        for j in char_list:
            if len(word_p) == len(p_s):
                print("word end")
                for i in scores.keys():
                    char_list.remove(i)
                break
            else:
                if j in word_p:
                    p_s=p_s+j
                    scores[j] = 1#this returns an integer value corresponding to char 
                    
        if ''.join(scores.keys()) == word_p:
            sep_scores[str(word_p)] = scores 
        else:
            sep_scores[str(word_p)] = {}
print(sep_scores)

>>> {'GUHD': {'G': 1, 'UH': 1, 'D': 1}, 'MAORNIHNG': {}, 'SER': {'S': 1, 'ER': 1}, 'MAY': {'M': 1, 'AY': 1}, 'SEHLF': {'S': 1, 'EH': 1, 'L': 1, 'F': 1}, 'BAENGK': {'B': 1, 'AE': 1, 'NG': 1, 'K': 1}}
```

Comment: Thanks, That didn't occur to me